# error C2259: cannot instantiate abstract class; or "how exactly should i be using virtual functions here?"

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, virtual

this involves some pretty tricky inheritance, but bear with me here.
My question isn't so much a specific error, but just "how would i do this specifically?"

the idea is to have an abstract base class Food (note that this are all oversimplified for the question)

```cpp
//parent of Animal
//parent of Plant
//~Food()
//Food()
#pragma once

class Food
{
public:
    Food(){}
    ~Food(){}



};
```

from that comes class animal and plants. i'm not too worried about plant right now
Animal needs to have the virtual functions Hunt and Eat

```cpp
#pragma once
#include "Food.h"


class Animal : public Food
{
//eat() which accepts a Food* type as an argument. it is an abstract virtual in this class, it has the form
//bool eat(Food* food)

//hunt() which accepts an stl list of Food* pointers to Food type objects. the food list is declared globally in main and passed here. it has the form
//hunt(list<Food*> &foodlist)
};
```

from that comes many more classes; Herbivore, Carnivore, Omnivore (which inherits from carnivore and herbivore). this is herbivore

```cpp
//Child of Animal
//Parent of Lemur, Koala, Squirrel, Omnivore

//~Herbivore()
//hunt(list<Food*&foodList):bool (only eats plant types)
#pragma once
#include "Animal.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class Herbivore : public virtual Animal
    {
    public:

        Herbivore() {}
        ~Herbivore(){}
        //eat() and hunt() are probably virtual here as well, as they aren't used directly, only the lower classes directly access them


};
```

and from those are the bottom most child classes, and they all have roughly this form. this is a Squirrel

```cpp
//child of Herbivore
//leaf node

#pragma once
#include "Animal.h"
#include "Herbivore.h"

class Squirrel : public Herbivore
{ 

        //bool eat() is fully defined here instead of being virtual.
        //bool hunt() is fully defined here instead of being a virtual.

       //both have the same argument lists as the virtuals in Animal



};
```

and here's main

```cpp
list<Food*> Food_list; //global list of Food items that will be passed to hunt()
int main()
{

    list<Food*>::iterator it = Food_list.begin();

    (*it)->eat(*it); //passing the iterator to itself as a test. this seems to work ok
    (*it)->hunt(Food_list); //however this, in my code, refuses to work for a few reasons

};
```

so basically everything inherits from food...but this is a bad thing.

i've tried several things with the following problems

i tried the initial version of the virtual functions in Animal, and nothing in food, it complained that Food has no function hunt

```
error C2039: 'hunt' : is not a member of 'Food'
```

....which is fair i suppose, although shouldn't it be looking at the Squirrel and not the food class?

i tried making a pure virtual in Food for eat and hunt, and from that point on, every attempt to instantiate any kind of leaf class (like a squirrel or tiger or whatever) returned the 'cannot instantiate abstract class' error.

```
error C2259: 'Squirrel' : cannot instantiate abstract class
```

i tried making the eat and hunt in food less abstract, like hunt(list &foodlist), but then it says "syntax error, identifier 'list' ", like it doesn't know what a list is....even after i include  in Food.h

```
error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'list'
```

and all of these errors are paired with the error "'Food::hunt': function does not take 1 arguments"

```
error C2660: 'Food::hunt' : function does not take 1 arguments
```

**my overall question is, how would you transpose this abstract virtual function from Animal to its leaf classes? and how exactly would you call it? basically everything i have tried as failed miserably**
**don't worry about what's inside eat() or hunt(), i'm just looking for proper declaration**

this github for the project is also available here
https://github.com/joekitch/OOP_JK_Assignment_4
if that is desired

Comment: Please include all relevant code and all error messages you are getting, verbatim, for one version of your code. People should be able to copy and paste your code, compile and get the same errors you are getting, without having to guess anything.

Comment: that's going to be a bit tricky, this particlar thing is 13 little classes, i just included examples from the top (food) down to the bottom (squirrel), but i'll add in the error messages as code blocks

Comment: You can and should reduce your code to a bare minimum,l that demonstrates the problem, and you have managed to pare it down to just 4 classes which is good. But then you went further and removed method declarations replacing them with comments. Please don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts,

- I'm assuming Herbivore is defined somewhere...
- Use virtual destructors
- When something tells you it can't be instantiated SOMEWHERE a Food(), Animal() constructor is being called.

Example code:

```
class Food
{
public:
    Food(){ }
    virtual ~Food(){ }
};

class Animal : public Food
{
 Animal() : Food() { }
 virtual Animal() { } //Cause C++

 virtual bool eat(Food* food) = 0;
 virtual hunt(list<Food*> &foodlist) = 0;
};

class Squirrel : public Herbivore
{ 
 Squirrel() : Herbivore() { }
 ~Squirrel() { } //not virtual

  bool eat(Food *food) { //stuff };
  void hunt(list<Food *> &foodlist) { //stuff };
};

list<Animal*> animal_list; //global list of Food items that will be passed to hunt()
int main()
{
    animal_list.push_back(new Squirrel()); // Make sure you fill the array?

    list<Food*>::iterator it = Food_list.begin();

    (*it)->eat(*it); //passing the iterator to itself as a test. this seems to work ok
    (*it)->hunt(animal_list); //however this, in my code, refuses to work for a few reasons

};
```

Comment: ok, i'll need to try this out. i remember attempting an implementation similar to this and it didn't work for some reason but perhaps this will work better.

Comment: Didn't work, it still claims that eat() and hunt() and not members of Food. mind you, i didn't make animal's constructor virtual because they would break absolutely everything else (even though my constructors are in the lowest-most classes).

Comment: This is of course not going to work. Food cannot eat or hunt, it in fact can do nothing at all, it's shown right here in the class declaration. Would you expect a pickle to be able to hunt?

Comment: exactly, which is why this problem is tricky. the list must contain Food type objects, i can't simply use Animals for everything (which would make much more sense). everything needs to inherit from food, even if food doesn't have hunt() or eat() within it. my question is how could that be made to work?

Comment: You cannot ask a food to hunt. Just don't do that. You have abilities of each kind of object specified in its class declaration. Ask of an object only things it can do.

Comment: AIiiighhhh, in my rush I totally missed that. Yes, only your subclasses can hunt/eat... fixing my example

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found involves dynamic casting.
basically, you need to cast the iterator pointer DOWN from a Food* type to something lower like an Herbivore or Animal type, either way the type must have the function you want fully defined within it

```cpp
Herbivore* temp = dynamic_cast<Herbivore*>(*it)
if ( temp ){
        cout << "iterator thing is a Herbivore " << endl;
        temp->hunt(Food_list);
    cout << "iterator thing is of the type " << typeid(temp).name() << endl;}
    else cout << "iterator is not a Herbivore " << endl;}
```

the above code will attempt to cast *it to an Herbivore* type. if it's successful (that is, *it's parent class is Herbivore), then Temp will be cast to the Herbivore* type specified on the left. if it fails, temp will be a NULL type. this temp pointer points to the same thing as the *it pointer....but it's simply treated as an Herbivore* instead of a Food*.